# How To Use Loops In TensorFlow Scopes and Sessions?

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can the following error be resolved?

> ValueError: Variable
>   RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/BasicLSTMCell/Linear/Matrix does not exist, or
>   was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None
>   in VarScope?

This error is thrown when I loop over "training" data to provide batched data to a MultiRNNCell based model (see **Main**). The `_model` (MultiRNNCell) and its constituent parts, i.e. BasicLSTMCell(s) in the code (see **Model**) below are not created via `tf.get_variable(...)` and thus repeated calls to the model cause the error.

**Main**:

```
def run_epoch(session, model, feed_dict):
    logits = model(inputs)
    sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()])
    scores = session.run([logits], feed_dict=feed_dict)

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    # ... Various tensorflow placeholders and variables.

    with tf.variable_scope('Train', reuse=None):
        train_model = lstm_model.MultiRNNLSTM(config, is_training=True)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        story_cnt = train_stories.shape[0]

        for epoch in range(5):
            print('----- Epoch', epoch, '-----')
            total_loss = 0
            for i in range(story_cnt // BATCH_SIZE):
                inst_story = train_stories[i * BATCH_SIZE: (i + 1) * BATCH_SIZE]
                inst_order = train_orders[i * BATCH_SIZE: (i + 1) * BATCH_SIZE]
                feed_dict = {story: inst_story, order: inst_order}

                run_epoch(sess, train_model, feed_dict)
```

**Model**:

```
    # With model class that encapsulates RNN instantiation and calls.

    with tf.variable_scope("RNN"):

        for time_step in range(self._config['num_steps']):
            if time_step > 0:
                print('Reusing RNN variables...')
                tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()

            (output, state) = self._model(inputs[:, time_step, :], state)
            outputs.append(output)
```

Comment: Your training loop looks very strange. You recreate the model and reinitialize its variables for every batch of data.